# How to avoid content from overlapping div border

Tags: css, border, overlapping

Here I have this markup:

```
   <div class="cabinet">
     <ul>
        <li>This is short</li>         
        <li>This one is longer</li>         
        <li>Yet this one is a lot more longer</li>         
     </ul>
   </div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
div.cabinet{
  width:120px;
  border-right:5px solid #e7e8e1;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

I need the content not to overlap the right border of the div but instead be padded some 5px away. Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahY2d/). I tried to play with z-index but it didn't help. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahY2d/1/)

How about the following:

```
div.cabinet{
  border-right:5px solid #e7e8e1;
  white-space:nowrap;
  display:inline-block;
  padding-right:5px;
}
```

Use inline-block to make the `div` fit the content, then add padding. If you only wish the child `ul` to do this, simply apply those properties to `div.cabinet ul` instead (as well as the border).

Comment: this really solves the problem. Do you have any solution for the situation when lots of ul's are used to create a treeview and when treeview is expanded the content still overlaps the border?

Comment: I mean for the static content (which is the case in the question) that's a perfectly working solution but unfortunately this breaks when content is toggled between diplay:none and display:block. I know the question does not mention this case but would be nice to know.

Answer (score 1):

Add a Padding to your UL or LI tag,

```
ul{padding:5px;} /** Will be applicable to all li's or you can also give it seperately **/
```

you can change that 5px value, but it will be enough !